# Editar información de un TableLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, tablas

Hice una tabla en la que puedo insertar datos y insertarlos en el `TableLayout`, pero quiero hacer más cosas como poder modificar los datos, eliminar, etc. pero sin necesidad de tener que usar una base de datos.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Nombre, Apellido;
    Button Insertar;
    TableLayout Datos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

        Nombre = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.etNombre );
        Apellido = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.etApellido );
        Insertar = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.btnInsertar );


        Insertar.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TableLayout datos = (TableLayout) findViewById ( R.id.tbDatos );
                String[] cadena = {Nombre.getText ().toString (), Apellido.getText ().toString ()};

                TableRow filas = new TableRow ( getBaseContext () );
                EditText Editar;
                //añadir las filas
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    Editar = new EditText ( getBaseContext () );
                    Editar.setGravity ( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );
                    Editar.setPadding ( 15, 15, 15, 15 );
                    //fondo
                    Editar.setBackgroundResource ( R.color.colorPrimaryDark );
                    Editar.setText ( cadena[i] );
                    Editar.setTextColor ( Color.WHITE );
                    filas.addView ( Editar );
                }
                datos.addView ( filas );
                Nombre.setText ( "" );
                Apellido.setText ( "" );
                Nombre.requestFocus ();

            }
        } );


    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

2.- Edite mi diseño y ahora cuando inserto un texto no me muestra donde debería, si no en la parte de abajo: (La imagen lo describe todo)

Insertar.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TableLayout datos = (TableLayout) findViewById ( R.id.tbDatos );
                String[] cadena = {Nombre.getText ().toString (), Apellido.getText ().toString ()};

```
            TableRow filas = new TableRow ( getBaseContext () );
            EditText Editar;
            //añadir las filas
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                Editar = new EditText ( getBaseContext () );
                Editar.setGravity ( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );
                Editar.setPadding ( 15, 15, 15, 15 );
                //fondo
                Editar.setBackgroundResource ( R.color.colorPrimaryDark );
                Editar.setText ( cadena[i] );
                Editar.setTextColor ( Color.WHITE );
                filas.addView ( Editar );
            }
            datos.addView ( filas );
            Nombre.setText ( "" );
            Apellido.setText ( "" );
            Nombre.requestFocus ();

        }
    } );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola hay varias preguntas ¿Cuales son los datos de tu tabla? ¿Que campos deseas modificar? ¿Que tipo de base de datos estas usando ya  que comentas no deseas SQLite? , Revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Ahí agregue una foto, en realidad es una tabla simple, ahi puedo insertar datos ahora quiero que de esos datos que tengo insertados pueda modificarlos, eliminar, etc.  Exacto yo no estoy usando ni sqlite ni ninguna base por que vi en internet que eso le llaman CRUD y se hace a través de una BD, pero yo no quiero utilizar una BD al menos por ahora no, por eso dije que es una tabla simple. Ayuda por favor

Comment: CRUD quiere decir Create, Read, Update, Delete. Y son acciones que podes realizar sobre un set de datos. No necesariamente implica que los datos esten en una base de datos. La base de datos se usa para persistir datos entre, digamos, que abres y cierras tu programa. sin embargo, la base de datos, puede ser cualquier cosa donde "persistas" (o sea, guardes para siempre) los datos. Tranquilamente podria ser un archivo de texto, si eso te sirviera.

Comment: Gracias por la descripción e información, pero no alivia mi urgencia :(

Comment: Y si intentas hacer  la vista con un recyclerView y trabajar con listas, capaz mejoraría la forma en que puedes hacer las cosas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aqui te dejo la solución que te podra servir:

Justo despues del for agrega dos botones que nos serviran como editar y eliminar los cuales realizaran tus acciones:

```
            Button removeButton = new Button(getBaseContext());
            removeButton.setText("Eliminar");
            removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    datos.removeView(filas);
                }
            });
            filas.addView(removeButton);
            //Para editar

            Button editButton = new Button(getBaseContext());
            editButton.setText("Editar");
            editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    datos.removeView(filas);
                    Nombre.setText(cadena[0]);
                    Apellido.setText(cadena[1]);
                }
            });
            filas.addView(editButton);
```

Nota: Para esto es necesario hacer final la variable filas.

Comment: Hola gracias, si me sirvió (en algunos aspectos), pero hice arreglos y ahora tengo otro problema ... agregaré la imagen arriba (editaré mi pregunta)

Comment: Perfecto, si hay algo mas en lo que te pueda ayudar, dime. Saludos.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda, espero me puedas ayudar con este nuevo problema, es el que dice numero 2. Mil gracias

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, creo que estas haciendo algo mal al agregar las vistas.

Comment: El código sigue siendo el mismo (el de arriba), el problema es cuando lo agrego. En la parte del Insertar.setOnClickListener.

Comment: Creo que si es necesario actualices en la publicacion tu nuevo codigo y asi poderte ayudar.

Comment: okey, listo lo añadí... aun que como te dije, es el mismo

Comment: Donde estas agregando los botones?